# What are the broken sword pieces for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, I have found a broken steel sword handle. Does it have a use? I did some research and found that there is also a broken steel sword blade, and a broken steel greatsword handle and blade, as well as their iron counterparts.  However, I can't find a use for them.  Any clue what they are for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the [broken steel sword handle](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Steel_Sword_Handle), the Wiki doesn't list any uses for it.  It lists it as a **Miscellaneous Item**.

The same goes for its [iron counterpart](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Iron_Sword_Handle), and the blades for each.  They cannot be repaired.  It seems that they are just junk items.

Comment: If you have hoarder tendencies, Skyrim is a really bad game for you...

Answer (score -1):

Just useless or for decorating your house, like I
 did.